# Customizing the Jquery Calendar

Tags: jquery, calendar, datepicker

I have never used Jquery before so I am quite stuck.

The datepicker calendar that gets displayed is not quite what I am looking for, so I am looking to customize it, but don't even know where to start since I am not sure how to use jquery.

So here is my current calendar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQLkY.jpg

All I want though is a single month displayed (default view), I don't want the year and month (not visible) dropdowns, and would like to disallow dates in the past (and the current day and tomorrow, if possible).

I found the jquery ui helper here http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ with examples, and I apparently all that I want is to really revert to the default:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Then for the min max date I was hoping someone might know how to use this code too to set mindate as the day after tomorrow, and maxdate as 1 year from now( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896276/customize-jquery-ui-datepicker )

```
$("#mydatepicker").datepicker({
maxDate: '',
minDate: '',

});
```

But I don't know how to implement any of this with Wordpress, help is appreciated on this-new to jquery and stuck.

Comment: This question isn't specifically related to WordPress. You'd be better of asking this question at [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here´s something to get you started.

1. Adapt the code below to your needs
2. Create an init.js file with notepad and paste your code in there
3. Save it in a logical place your theme folder (the JS directory for example)
4. [Register and enqueue](http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-load-scripts-in-wordpress-themes) this file (make sure to load it after jquery)

Datepicker set up:

```
/* http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers */
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  /* For all options see http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ */    
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    defaultDate: +2,   
    minDate: 0, 
    maxDate: '+2y',
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    showAnim: 'fadeIn',
    showButtonPanel: true,
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: 'Pick a date',
    showOn: 'both'
  });

});
```

Comment: I think I messed something up. I already had a similar process to setup flex slider so I tried to follow the same steps. Here are my screentshots http://imgur.com/vWhZL (calendar still old version) , http://imgur.com/Q9Lqc (functions) , http://imgur.com/5QB7p the file

Comment: Looks like a css issue. Difficult to tell without actually seeing the site. Are all stylesheets loaded in the right order?

Comment: Oh, what you were seeing was a css issue, but thats because all three months were displaying

Comment: Here is a better pic http://imgur.com/AoDoe

Comment: Ok, the code I provided was for your own instance of the datepicker, but you want to customize the datepicker from the Gravity form plugin. Quite an important detail as it requieres a different approach. It´s a paid plugin so I´ve no idea how they set this up. I suggest you ask for help on their support forums: http://www.gravityhelp.com/forums/tags/date-picker

Comment: Okay, perfect. They are usually a very helpful group. Thanks for your help getting me started Mattvic, it is much appreciated

Comment: For anyone who comes by this later--the only change need was to change #datepicker to .datepicker